# How do I exclude certain test classes from being compiled in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have inherited a project whose unit tests (*Test.java) and integration tests (*IT.java) are unfortunately stored in the same folder (src/test/java).

How do I exclude the integration test classes (they end with *IT.java) from being compiled during the compileTestJava phase in Gradle?

In Maven, this can be accomplished via the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Additionally, during the integration test phase, I can ignore the unit tests as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```